# Laplace transform of survival probability for stochastic diffusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $Y_t$ be a killed process defined by 
\begin{eqnarray}
Y_t = X_t \quad \mbox{if } t<\xi,\\
Y_t = 0 \quad \mbox{if } t\geq\xi.
\end{eqnarray}
where $\xi$ is a random time such that 
$$
\xi=\inf \{ t\geq 0 : \int_0^t h(X_u)du>e\}
$$
$e$ is a exponential distribution with mean 1.

$X_t$ is governed by the following SDE:
$dX_t=\mu(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t.$

I am solving some exercise to compute 
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda T}P(\xi>T)dT.
$$
That is, the Laplace transform of survival probability.

In addition, function $h(x)$ is given by 
$$
h(x)=\beta+x^{\alpha}.
$$

I couldn't proceed with this step..
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda T}P(\xi>T)dT=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda T}e^{-\int_0^Th(X_u)du}dT.
$$

I think this problem should be linked to ODE form ...
Hlep please

Comment: Indeed the result is $$\int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda+\beta)t}E(e^{-Z_t})\,dt,$$ with $$Z_0=0,\qquad dZ_t=(X_t)^\alpha dt.$$ To go further, one might want to compute $E(e^{-Z_t})$, which, with no further information on $(b,\sigma)$, does not seem very tractable.